# Старый компьютер не читает новую флешку

Tags: flash-память

Есть старенький компьютер Pentium III,  600 МГц с портами USB ещё 1.0. Взял я новую флешку Transcend на 16 Гб объёмом. Не хочет её видеть этот старый комп!

Другие флешки видит (на 2 и на 8 Гб).

Может флешка не рабочая? Проверил я эту флешку на другом, новом компьютере - работает. Записал фильм на неё, поставил в DVD-плеер - показывает плеер фильм, флешку видит.

Вот загадка. Может быть особо старые компьютеры флешки больше 8 Гб не видят? Помню, у знакомого была проблема похожая. Встретились мы в городе и захотел он мне немедленно фотки с флешки показать. И вот у него тоже была новая флешка на 16 Гб. Решили зайти в Интернет-клуб, взять компьютер. А там компьютер был тоже старенький. И вот не видит он совершенно нормальную, рабочую флешку, и всё! Отчего это может быть?

Comment: Какая операционная система на пациенте и что за флэшка (производитель)?

Comment: Операционная система Windows XP Professional Service Pack 2.Флешка Transcend JetFlash 300 объёмом 16 GB.

Comment: Ко всем usb-портам пробовали подключать? (понимаю, вопрос граничит с идиотизмом, но и такое встречалось в практике))

Comment: Вопрос НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ! Вовсе не идиотский :)Нет, не ко всем портам. К одному. НО (!) именно на этот один и тот же USB-порт я успешно много раз подключал другие ТРИ разные флешки меньшей ёмкости. В старых компьютерах USB-разъёмы только сзади, что неудобно. Поэтому у меня там вставлен удлинитель USB, который некоторые называют "косичкой". В этот удлинитель всегда и вставляю флешки. Попробую другие порты (любопытно стало!) и отпишусь.* * * * * *Попробовал! Без толку. Либо совсем не видит флешку, либо всё-таки видит, что вставлен съёмный диск, но если открыть Свойства, то там комп ничего не видит.

Comment: Если выбрать "Форматировать", то никак не реагирует. А на другом компьютере я эту флешку на всякий случай уже переформатировал на старый проверенный FAT32. Но нет :). В старом компьютере пишет (если удаётся открыть "Свойства" этой флешки), что файловая система: не определена.

Comment: Ага! Значит все-таки кое-как обнаружить ее компу удается... Предположение тоже из разряда "так себе", но может попробовать обновить драйверы на материнку + поискать дрова для флэшки? Для Win98 точно надо было ставить драйверы, XP и выше вроде как сами их ставят, но мало ли...

Answer (score 1):

> Проверил я эту флешку на другом, новом компьютере - работает. Записал фильм на неё, поставил в DVD-плеер - показывает плеер фильм, флешку видит.

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: А старый компьютер почему эту флешку не видит? Я уже купил ещё другую флешку на 8 ГБайт Silicon Power Helios 101. Работает нормально!

Comment: Если хочется докопаться до истины, то давайте плясать от того какая мать, на каком чипсете, больше информации. А то сейчас выяснится, что мать особо бюджетная и производитель вообще не предусматривал, что туда (в USB) больше 1 Gb пхать будут.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите USB interface, ваш комп имеет USB 1.0 , а у флешки 2.0 , вот и (**не**)получается.

Comment: Имхо, от интерфейса (USB 1.0/2.0) это не зависит. Иначе бы и девайсы на USB 3.0 не работали бы на порте USB 2.0, чего не наблюдается)

Answer (score 0):

Запусти линуксовый `liveCD` и попробуй подключить флешку. Там также есть инструменты для работы с `hdd` для флешки тоже должны подойти. Если заработает, будем дальше думать.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, проще купить PCI-платку USB 2.0, дабы на будущее исключить такие проблемы.

Comment: из коммента ТС: "Я уже купил ещё другую флешку на 8 ГБайт Silicon Power Helios 101. Работает нормально".  Так что дело тут вряд ли в интерфейсе.

Comment: у меня просто закралось подозрение, что порты на матери могут не тянуть по питанию. Хотя это только гипотеза. Не видя компа ТС, не могу утверждать.

Answer (score 0):

[@tolan](/users/570/tolan) прав,[@Nikolja](/users/1167/nikolja), у вас флешка usb 2? usb 3?

```
PS:USB 3.0 поддерживается не всеми операционными системами. В первую очередь это касается Windows XP.
```

Comment: Так... смотрю на упаковку от флешки :-) . Китайцы "пишуть", что Connection Interface: USB 2.0

Comment: Я выше сказал> Если хочется докопаться до истины, то давайте плясать от того какая мать, на каком чипсете, больше информации

Comment: :) А как можно самостоятельно определить, какая материнская плата и чипсет?

Comment: Попробуйте http://www.hwinfo.com/, если linux, то команда hwinfo

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Hwinfo выдаёт такую информацию: Motherboard ABIT i815E-W83627HF ; chipset Intel 815EP (Solano-3) + ICH2

Comment: И шо? :) Ваш приговор? На рассвете расстрелять? :-D

Comment: Abit накрылся медным тазом, BIOS Вы не перепрошьете, в морг.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри в ESCD (таблица после POST) определяется ли название и модель флешки. Если не успеваешь увидеть, выстави загрузку boot device с чего-нибуть левого (LS-120, например). Если определяет - верни настройки и попытайся скачать дрова (факт! У меня Transcend JetFlash D133193 8Gb, те же проблемы). Если не определяет - ну, не судьба...